# Create custom user model extending user built in model and working on MySQL database loopback

Tags: mysql, authentication, loopback

I'm trying to use the built-in model User in loopback to login my user. I have a custom model named Customer that is connecting with a mysql database and that extends User model. But I don't understand how to make User model working on MySQL database. May someone explain me how I can extend User built-in model to use the login system on the MySQL database.
If you need any further information, ask me.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know if this ofer any advantages. I need to migrate my old php app into loopback API but I have many users already registered in the MySQL database. So I just want to use the same database to keep them registered.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. May I suggest a link to the loopback API documentation may assist people looking at this question? The 'loopback' tag is not useful for that. The one I found was for node.js